# Why can't you use C++11 brace initialization with macros?

Tags: c++, c++11

I just discovered that you cannot always use brace initialization when passing arguments to macros. I found this when an ASSERT() macro failed to compile. However, the following example illustrates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define PRINT_SIZE( f ) cout << "Size=" << (f).size() << endl;

int main()
{
  PRINT_SIZE( string("ABC") );  // OK, prints: "Size=3"
  PRINT_SIZE( string{"ABC"} );  // OK, prints: "Size=3"

  PRINT_SIZE( string("ABCDEF",3) ); // OK, prints: "Size=3"
  PRINT_SIZE( string{"ABCDEF",3} ); // Error: macro 'PRINT_SIZE' passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1

   return 0;
}
```

Is there a reason why macros cannot be made to work with brace initialization?

**Edit:**

I have since discovered that you can also use a variadic macro, and that solves the problem perfectly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define PRINT_SIZE( ... ) cout << "Size=" << (__VA_ARGS__).size() << endl;

int main()
{
  PRINT_SIZE( string("ABC") );  // OK, prints: "Size=3"
  PRINT_SIZE( string{"ABC"} );  // OK, prints: "Size=3"

  PRINT_SIZE( string("ABCDEF",3) ); // OK, prints: "Size=3"
  PRINT_SIZE( string{"ABCDEF",3} ); // OK, prints: "Size=3"

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Macro language is a pretty primitive language, unconnected with most of the C++ grammar.

Comment: Commas separate macro arguments.

Comment: To complement the answers, *The sequence of preprocessing tokens bounded by the outside-most matching parentheses forms the list of
arguments for the function-like macro.* ***The individual arguments within the list are separated by comma
preprocessing tokens, but comma preprocessing tokens between matching inner parentheses do not separate
arguments.*** *If there are sequences of preprocessing tokens within the list of arguments that would otherwise
act as preprocessing directives, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Nope, they don't. Commas in inner parentheses intentionally do not separate arguments. It would be very easy to make the C++ preprocessor support inner braces as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The list is split into several macro parameters. When you write

```
PRINT_SIZE( string{"ABCDEF",3} );
```

This attempts to expand the macro `PRINT_SIZE` with two parameters, one `string{"ABCDEF"` and one `3}`, which fails. This can be worked around in many cases (including yours) by adding another pair of parentheses:

```
PRINT_SIZE( (string{"ABCDEF",3}) );
```

These parentheses prevent the splitting of the argument, so that `PRINT_SIZE` is expanded with a single argument `(string{"ABCDEF",3})` (note that the parentheses are part of the argument).

Comment: +1 for the workaround. So would it not be good idea to update the C++11 preprocessor to treat {} the same as ()?

Comment: I think a useful discussion of that question would be longer than even a large number of SO comments. It's a thought, but I wonder how much existing code would be broken by the change -- currently, braces can be simply passed as macro parameters. It doesn't just concern braces, either -- consider `SOME_MACRO(std::is_same<A, B>::value)`, for example.

Comment: @Barnett, Preprocessor changes don't fly too well. Many would prefer that the preprocessor becomes obsolete from a feature that at least replaces its functionality without all the bad included in macros. AFAIK, the preprocessor is the exact same as C99, too, minus some small things that have more to do with C vs. C++ than the preprocessor itself.

Comment: Parantheses don't work for me. Instead the original error i got `statement expression not allowed at file scope`.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is a reason: The preprocessor is not aware of braces. It only respects string literals and parentheses, to other C/C++ language structures it is ignorant. As such, the call

```
PRINT_SIZE( string{"ABCDEF",3} );
```

is parsed as a macro invocation with two parameters `string{"ABCDEF"` and `3}`. Since the macro `PRINT_SIZE()` expects only one parameter, the preprocessor bails out. Note that the C++ compiler has not even been invoked at this point!

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
#define SOME_BRACE  \
{                   \
    6, 8, 1, 3, 7,  \
    1, 4, 2, 0, 9   \
}

#define BRACE_SIZE(brace) (sizeof((int[]) SOME_BRACE) / sizeof(int))

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int array[BRACE_SIZE(SOME_BRACE)] = SOME_BRACE, i, s;

    for (i = 0, s = 0; i < BRACE_SIZE(SOME_BRACE); i++) {
        s = s + array[i];
    }
    /* 41 is expected */
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how this help? You mean I have to define a macro to pass a brace initialization expression into a macro? That would defeat the purpose of a macro.